# Checking range for textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 textboxes on my form for which I'm trying to restrict the input. Here is a more detailed description of what I'm trying to do:

Code a method named `IsValidData` that checks that the Operand 1 and Operand 2 text boxes contain a decimal value between 0 and 1,000,000 (non-inclusive) and that the Operator text box contains a valid operator.

I know the way that I did this is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it. The way I thought of it when writing the if statement is this:

check to make sure the value is >0 AND <=100 for the input in the `txtOperand1` textbox and then did the same for the other textbox. Can someone please give suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
double operand1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtOperand1.Text);
double operand2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtOperand2);


        if ((operand1 > 0 && operand1 <= 100) &&
            (operand2 > 0 && operand2 <= 100))
            return true;
```

Comment: you should first convert your textbox.Text string to number. 
for example `int.Parse (txtOperand1.Text) > 0`

Comment: I updated my post, would that be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Can you print the value of `operand2`? You might have a transcription error when writing the question, but converting a control instead of its `.Text` property could be the problem, otherwise.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem! You get rep from it too.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
return decimal.TryParse(txt.Text, out decimal val) && (val > 0m & val < 1000000m)
```