# C# - range for textbox inputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a form with 4 text boxes. I'm trying to code a method that checks to make sure the inputs in the 1st and 3rd textbox are between 0 and 100. This is an example that I found. But, I'm confused on how you can check both text boxes if there is only 1 parameter for the textbox. I know that you need to convert the inputs because text boxes only accept strings. What I'm having trouble with is after converting the 2 text boxes, how do you check both of them in this if statement. Do you convert both textboxes, give them different variable names, and then use those variables in 2 different if statements? Would it be correct to just repeat this statement for the other textbox?

```
public bool IsWithinRange(TextBox textBox, string name, decimal min, decimal max)
        {
            number = txtOperand1.Text, txtOperand2.Text;

            if (number < 0 || number > 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".", "Entry Error");
                textBox.Focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: You should investigate the Wonders of the NumericUpDown

Comment: This would be the method that checks either textbox. So, if you have a `txtbox1` and a `txtbox2`, you'd pass them into the method as `textbox`, the name of the control as the `name` and your min and max values, but as @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp pointed out, you'd be better off with a `NumericUpDown` control here.

Comment: I haven't learned NumericUpDown yet or used it before but after reading about it I tried to use it. It's still confusing to me so I tried changing the code back to what I orginally had. Is this what you mean by putting them both as the variable name: number = txtOperand1.Text, txtOperand2.Text;?

Comment: _1st and 3rd textbox are between 0 and 100_ so you want to get a range by using two `TextBox`es?

Comment: I don't want to get the range from the textbox, rather, I want to restrict the numeric value the user can enter for the 1st and 3rd textbox. @someuser

Comment: You are duplicating your own questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117930/checking-range-for-textboxes/60121751#60121751

Answer (score 2):

To validate the values of `TextBox` you just need to parse each fileds data/text as `int` simply parsing & a checking method is enough.

As @Jimi pointed out, for `WinForms`:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int f = 0, t = 0;

    if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out f))
    {
        // successfully parsed 
    }

    if (Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out t))
    {
        // successfully parsed 

    }

    // or just use parse..
    int f1 = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int t1 = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);


    if (rangeCheck(f, t))
    {
       // Success 
    }
}
bool rangeCheck(int first, int third)
{
    return (first >= 0 && first <= 100 && third >= 0 && third <= 100);
}
```

[image: design your form, just an example:]
Your Form Designer code: modify according to your needs

```
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 75);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 123);
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 168);
            this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
            this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox3.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this.textBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 211);
            this.textBox4.Name = "textBox4";
            this.textBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox4.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 262);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
```

> Using `WPF`

```
 <TextBox Name="box1"  ...other_properties  />
 <TextBox Name="box2"  ...other_properties  />
 <TextBox Name="box3"  ...other_properties  />
 <TextBox Name="box4"  ...other_properties  />

 <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Check for validity" ...other properties />
```

Now handle those:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            int f = 0, t = 0;

            if (Int32.TryParse(box1.Text, out f))
            {
               // successfully parsed 
            }

            if (Int32.TryParse(box3.Text, out t))
            {
                // successfully parsed 

            }

            // or just use parse..
            int f1 = Int32.Parse(box1.Text);
            int t1 = Int32.Parse(box3.Text);


            if (rangeCheck(f, t))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Both are within 0 and 100");
            }
        }

        bool rangeCheck(int first, int third)
        {
            return (first >= 0 && first <= 100 && third >= 0 && third <= 100);
        }
```

Comment: All right. It's not exactly what you do in Winforms, though. You could, for example - if you really want to use a TextBox for the input - create a Custom Control, in CreateParams add [ES_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles) to styles, so the TextBox only accepts numbers, then, since you're there, override WndProc and verify the input before it arrives to the control's *view* :) Or use an `ErrorProvider` class to give visual clues when the input is wrong, then Validate and notify. But, ok, the OP, apparently, is not *there*, yet.

Comment: As a note, if the operator identifies a division, the divisor operand cannot be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to make sure the inputs in the 1st and 3rd textbox are

between 0 and 100.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int m = 0;
            int n = 0;
            bool a = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out  m);
            bool b = int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out n);
            if(a&b==false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter number");
            }
            else
            {
                bool t = IsWithinRange(m,"textbox1", 1, 100);
                t= IsWithinRange(n, "textbox3", 1, 100);
            }

        }
        public bool IsWithinRange(int a, string name,decimal min, decimal max)
        {
            if(a>=min&&a<=max)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " is between " + min + " and " + max + ".", "Right");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".", "Entry Error");
            }
            return true;
        }
```